# Problem with simplifying $\frac{(3+h)^2-9}{(3+h)-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I need help simplifying
$$
{(3+h)^2-9\over (3+h)-3}.
$$

The answer is $6+h$.

I keep getting $h$.

Comment: Could you, please, show how you're getting $h$?

Comment: @CiaPan: Probably $(3+h)^2 = 3^2 + h^2$...

Comment: Yep that's it, I wasn't factoring out correctly

Comment: Question is resolved in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{(3+h)^2-9}{(3+h)-3}=\frac{(3+h)(3+h)-9}{h}=\frac{(h^2+6h+9)-9}{h}=\frac{h^2+6h}{h}=\;?
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** 
 $$ a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$$

Answer (score 0):

You got h, because you assumed that $(3+h) ^2 - 9 = ((3+h) - 3)((3+h) - 3)$

But it's $((3+h) - 3)((3+h) + 3)$.

After the simplification you'll get $h+6$.

Important: You have to point that $h$ is not equal to $0$.